# In ExtJS, how can I specify default configurations for nested elements when extending an object?

Tags: extjs

Using ExtJS 4.1.3, I'd like to create a common Ext.data.Store to use site-wide that serves as a basis for multiple pages.  Here's the common code I have:

```
Ext.define('Common.data.Store', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    pageSize: 50,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        timeout: 1000 * 120,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            totalProperty: 'results'
        }
    }
});
```

Then, I extend Common.data.Store and configure only those fields which are unique to the page:

```
Ext.define('Test.store.Test', {
    extend: 'Common.data.Store',
    model: 'testModel',
    proxy: {
        api: {
            read:'/test/getTest/'
        },
        reader: {
            root: 'test'
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is the configs aren't merged recursively, so the nested configs in the extension of the common store are completely overwriting the nested configs of the common store.  I need to know of a way to essentially do an Ext.apply on the config in order to recursively merge the configs.  Is this possible?  I've looked into the constructor config property, but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: You would need to merge them together inside the constructor of `Common.data.Store`.

Comment: I've tried that, but the config argument passed into the constructor doesn't seem to have everything necessary to do so.

Comment: @astonius you will have to do that manually, there is no utility in Ext that merges recursively those properties.

Comment: @Andrei, I'm fine with that, but where and how would I do it?

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:

The parent class:

```
Ext.define('Common.data.Store', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    config: {
        pageSize: 50,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            timeout: 120000,
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                totalProperty: 'results'
            }
        }
    },
    constructor: function(config)
    {
        this.initConfig(Ext.merge(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Common.data.Store.prototype.getInitialConfig())), Ext.merge(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.getInitialConfig())), config)));
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

The child class:

```
Ext.define('Test.store.Test', {
    extend: 'Common.data.Store',
    model: 'Test.model.Test',
    config: {
        proxy: {
            api: {
                read:'/test/getTest/'
            },
            reader: {
                root: 'test'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I recommend you reading the rules of this forum. An answer does not ask other questions.